# Rails 3 date_select for year only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, select

I have a form in my Rails 3 app where I want to create a `select` tag for just the year on a method `:grad_year`. I have everything working - and storing - properly using `date_select` and adding `:discard_month` and `:discard_day`. However when I render `@profile.grad_year` I get the month and day values. So I'm wondering how to store and render  **only** the year for `@profile.grad_year`?

Here is the form:

```
<%= f.date_select :grad_year, {:start_year => Time.now.year, :end_year => Time.now.year - 95, :discard_day => true, :discard_month => true}, :selected => @profile.grad_year %>
```

In my migration:

```
t.date :grad_year
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Rails has a `select_year` helper:

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/select_year

So your code should look like:

```
f.select_year(Date.today, :start_year => Time.now.year, :end_year => Time.now.year - 95, :field_name => 'grad_year')
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried something similar but got an error: `undefined method select_year for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x1085b2198>`

Comment: Try excluding the `f.` at the beginning.

Comment: You can just set it in your create action: `params[:profile][:grad_year] = params[:grad_year]`

Comment: `select_year` accepts an `html_options` hash as the third argument. You can pass in `:name` and `:id` values to match the rest of your form.

Answer (score 5):

Assembling all of the above from @alex_peattie's answer, I arrived at the following:

```
<%= select_year Date.today, :start_year => Time.now.year, :end_year => Time.now.year - 95, :field_name => :grad_year, :prefix => :profile  %>
```

As with the OP's question, my case was done within a `form_for` block, so `f.select_year` threw an exception.  But if you just use the documented `:field_name` option, the tag will have the id `date_grad_year` and name `date[grad_year]` which are not what Rails expects.  Using the (documented only at the very top of the API) `:prefix` option changes `date` to `profile`.

So this is better than the #@%$^*& html_options hash, which, despite using rails for 5 years now, I cannot seem to get right without five tries :-).

Oh Rails, how I love you, yet at the same time am sure glad Stack Overflow is around to help us all understand your delightful idiosyncrasies!

Comment: A more general solution to this would be `select_year f.object.field_name ... :prefix => f.object_name`

Answer (score 2):

This select_year function is totally screwy.

Here is finally what works:

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
 <%= select_year current_user.birth_year, { :prompt => "Year", 
                                            :start_year => Time.zone.now.year - 13, 
                                            :end_year => Time.zone.now.year - 80, 
                                            :field_name => :birth_year, 
                                            :prefix => :user }, 
                                            class:"form-control" %>
<% ... %>
```

it aught to be like this in rails:

```
<%= f.select_year :birth_year, { :prompt => "Year", 
                                            :start_year => Time.zone.now.year - 13, 
                                            :end_year => Time.zone.now.year - 80}, 
                                            class:"form-control" %>
```

Comment: Seriously... what the heck RoR... *sigh*