# Rails date/year field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, datetime

I want to input only year field in my rails  form. I tried `select_year` but it doesn't work for me. `select_date` also gave me problem because my form models is in association.  Is there any alternative idea.

Comment: what problem you faced with `select_year` and `select_date`?

Comment: Also you want year drop down or input field?

Comment: f.select_year gave error

Comment: select_date gave me data in three fields

Comment: what are those fields?

Comment: Both situation doesn't work because of models association.

Answer (score 1):

Ref:- [`select_year`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#M002269)

```
# Generates a select field for years that defaults to the current year that
# is named 'birth' rather than 'year'
<%= f.select_year(Date.today, :field_name => 'birth') %>
```

but if you don't have any column then just use

```
<%= select_year(Date.today) %>
```

Ref [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11164632/297087)  and try something like

```
<%= select_year Date.today, :start_year => Time.now.year, :end_year => Time.now.year - 95, :field_name => :grad_year, :prefix => :profile  %>
```

Comment: undefined method `select_year' for #<SimpleForm::FormBuilder:0x007f8604248858>

Comment: just use `<%= select_year(Date.today, :field_name => 'birth') %>` then

Comment: this works only for form, but it gave me problem when submit data

Comment: cause, models are in association, and accepts_nested_attributes