# replace year to "Present" on dropdownlist in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a below code of dropdownlist:

```
<%= f.select :year, (1995..Time.now.year).to_a, :include_blank => {:year => "Select year"} %>
```

Then the above code shows a dropdownlist with values from "1995" to "2014" but I want to raplace "2014" to "Present" in the dropdownlist, so what should I do. Kindly suggest me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the select_year method [Rails 3 date_select for year only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215230/rails-3-date-select-for-year)